# Installing/ Uninstalling Firefox extentions on specific machines

Tags: windows-7, firefox

Not found anything about this in the webs, although I feel like it should be available somewhere. All my firefoxes are connected to my firefox account and this means if I install an extension on one, it is automtically installed on the others, if possible. However i don't always want everything that i use on the desktop in my laptop. Is there a way to individually install/ uninstall them on a machine to machine basis?

I'm running windows 7 and firefox 62.0.2 (64-bit)

I've seen that i can disable the syncing of addons completely, but this is not really what I'm looking for. There are some addons that I do want on all machines

Comment: You probably need to decide between *"the lesser of two evils."*  In other words, there isn't any option within the `Sync Settings` related to your Firefox Account to only synchronize **some** of the add-ons.  If you choose stop synchronizing add-ons between your desktop and your laptop, you can customize each one of them as much as you want.  On the other hand, if you leave it enabled it will emulate *all* of the add-ons between those two machines.  Ultimately, unless someone else chimes in with a solution I haven't heard of before, you will need to choose which method is easier.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox supports Add-on Collections, which offer an alternative
way of syncing add-ons. Instead of syncing all add-ons, you create your own collection
of them and use it.

Collections let you save and share lists of add-on listings on `addons.mozilla.org`
and subscribe to them through a URL.

You could therefore disable the syncing of add-ons completely,
create a collection of the add-ons you do want to share
and use instead that collection for syncing.

For more information see the Mozilla article
[Collections and User Profiles have a new look](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2018/07/26/collections-user-profiles-new-look/).
As I'm not using this feature, you will need to explore it yourself.